Cambridge Capital Controversy: Why is Reswitching and Reverse Capital Deepening a Problem Exactly?
This question requires some background so Im going to be a bit more formal than usual for a question I post here.
Introduction
The Cambridge Capital Controversy is a hard thing to understand in the reading of history of economic thought.
Two phenomenon which are discussed in great detail are the phenomenon of "Reswitching" and "Reverse Capital Deepening". The way I have understood each of these two are as follows:
Reswitching

A monotone relationship between the Marginal Product of Capital and interest rate is not guaranteed.

the usual example of cost minimization with difference in sequencing of production can be found here , this can be more clearly illustrated in the case of a firm that has two methods of production and has the following profit function:
$$\pi = \max\{pk^{0.5}-rk,p(k-0.1)^{0.2}-rk\}$$
It follows that the optimality condition of $r=MPK$ is defined as:
$$r=\max\{0.5pk^{-0.5},0.2p(k-0.1)^{-0.8}\}$$
Which gives us a non monotone relationship between $MPK$ and $r$.


Graphs of each of these conditions can be seen by here:
profit function: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qyz4lj1tiu 
MPK curve: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/axab4mtvnw
Reverse Capital Deepening

An implication of Reswitching.

This is when more capital intensive methods are employed at higher interest rates and less capital intensive methods are employed at lower interest rates (contradicting the law of diminishing marginal return on capital).

Instead of a inverse relationship between interest rate and capital utilization there is a positive relationship.


Question: What does this have to do with aggregate production functions and their problems theoretically?
It should be noted that the literature broadly discusses the rarity of reswitching in practice. But I have no clue what the issue of reswitching has to do with there being a "problem" with aggregate production functions to begin with.
TLDR: How does reswitching and/or capital reversal present a challenge to the aggregate production function?
Note: The most recent advance on the irrelevance of reswitching I have found is here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bryC6JVxreA&t=397s
